# How can I keep my service alive after finishing its work, waiting for data from another class?

Tags: java, android, android-service

i have a class(location2.java) that finds location for me,I use this code in my class :
[What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-on-a)

and I have a service that override that abstract "locationResult";Now i want my service after running its codes,service doesn't finish and stay alive for receiving location from location2.java.

appreciating any help for this.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    Location2.LocationResult locate = new Location2.LocationResult() {
        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location location1, Boolean Gps, Boolean Net) {

            if (location1 != null) {
                Log.e("Loc", String.valueOf(location1.getLatitude()));

            }

            try {
                //this is a method that i want to be run after receiving location from location2.java
                json_maker(location1, speed_computation(location1), Gps, Net);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
    Location2 location = new Location2();
    location.getLocation(context, locate);


    return Service.START_FLAG_REDELIVERY;

}
```

Comment: The most successful way is to use return START_STICKY.

Comment: @W4R10CK thank u,but as I know "return" in services is used for a time that service was terminated by system ,and if service wants to restart, multiple constants for example START_STICKY can be used.doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The most successful way is to use return START_STICKY.

> "and if service wants to restart, multiple constants for example START_STICKY can be used.doesn't it?" - Yes, we can use.
>
> START_STICKY
>   Constant to return from `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)` if this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the started state but don't retain this delivered intent. [Developer guide: Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY)

Comment: thanks , I want my service stay alive, i do not have any idea about time that my service was killed.what can i do my service doesn't finish after doing its methods, and wait for another class?

Comment: @sama There are two Service IntentService and Service. IntentService stopped by the user after work has done. Service keeps working in the background and in Main UI Thread. Use a Thread to run your service. 
Select and upvote for the correct answer :).

Comment: I'll be so thankful if u say a bit in details,how does thread help me?

Comment: @sama http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html use this link for Service documents and uses.

Comment: @ W4R10CK thank u,but i couldn't do any thing for my code.